# GCE Secret Manager display test secret via php application

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-secret-manager

I am new to Secret manager and I am trying to display a test secret using a php app.
All I get when the app is deployed is an error 500.
I gave my xxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com service account the required role according to gcp documentation (Secret Manager Secret Accessor + Storage Object Admin)
I also installed composer from the cloud shell so I really cannnot spot what I am doing the wrong way.

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "^9.0.0"
    },
    "require": {
        "google/cloud-secret-manager": "^1.2"
    }
}
```

this is how my code looks like:

```
<?php 
    use Google\Cloud\SecretManager\V1\SecretManagerServiceClient;
     
    $projectId = 'myproject';
    $secretId = 'mysecret';
    $versionId = '1';
    $client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
    $name = $client->secretVersionName($projectId, $secretId, $versionId);
    $response = $client->accessSecretVersion($name);
    $payload = $response->getPayload()->getData();
    printf('Plaintext: %s', $payload);
?>
```

Thank you for your help...I don't know what to try anymore :-(

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I can hardly see what is wrong from the logs :-(  I can see the response is 500 but not much that really helps...

Comment: It's difficult to debug without the logs. You can see this article to find your application logs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/viewing-service-logs

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying helping me. Hugely appreciated. the logs says :   `code`"textPayload": "[start] 2021/01/02 12:03:59.775036 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit",
    "insertId": "5ff0612f000bd5d499c4496d",
    "resource": {
      "type": "gae_app",
      "labels": {
        "module_id": "default",
        "version_id": "20210102t114630",
        "project_id": "myproject",
        "zone": "us12"
      }`code`

Comment: Well...finally I believe something is missing ...`code`2021/01/04 11:29:42 [error] 23#23: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Cloud\SecretManager\V1\SecretManagerServiceClient' not found in /workspace/form.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /workspace/index.php(5): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /workspace/form.php on line 11" while reading response header from upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: , request: "GET /form.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/google-config/php-fpm.sock:", host: "mycompany-training-dev.uc.r.appspot.com"`code`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to make this work. As a typical noob I made a lot of nonsense ^^ so long story short:
First I have (had?) a bad habit to build my app from the google shell (not sdk). Nothing wrong with that I guess (except it is actually less convenient) but in this usecase you need to link a json file containing access key to your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environnment variable so it will have the right to query secret manager.I did not know how to do that without the sdk. So once the app deployed using the sdk and the json file properly assigned, it was better. Then I had an autoload.php error I managed to fix using this article in french : https://www.journaldunet.fr/web-tech/developpement/1441107-comment-corriger-l-erreur-require-vendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream/
Thank you guys for trying to help me. I learnt one or two interresting things with this issue....Everyday is a school day ^^